# how to get a matrix from user then put it into a 2d list

Tags: python, list

I wonder how to get some information (obviously a matrix) from user and then put all those numbers into a 2D list?
So I know there's probably prewritten function to do it, but I wanna make my own!

the Code down here and a description is my work that clearly doesn't work!!!!!

description: the program aquire user to enter a matrix in this form: a a a;a a a;a a a;
which 'a' is an arbitrary number, and ';' points where a row ends!
Almost like how we assign matrixes in matlab!

my code for the goal:

```
str = input("Enter a numerical squence: ")
print(len(str))
index_counter = 0
matrix = []
while index_counter < len(str) :
    rows = []
    while str[index_counter] != ";":
        if str[index_counter] == " ":
            index_counter += 1
        else:
            rows.append(int(str[index_counter]))
            index_counter += 1
    matrix.append(rows)   
print(matrix)
```

Comment: Split (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) the string around ';' to get the rows, then split each row around ' ' (base split) to get individual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using needless loops upon loops, just use split method which splits a string into list by delimiter?

Firstly split the entire string into 1d list by ';' then each list elements into sub lists by splitting using ' '

> ```
> #getting input from user
> inpt=str(input('enter matrix'))
>
> #splitting string into 1D list of strings by ;
> Matrix=inpt.split(';')[:-1]
>
> #splitting substrings into sub list by ' '
> for i in range(0,len(x)):
>     Matrix[i]=Matrix[i].split(' ')
>
> #display matrix
> print(Matrix)
> ```

Comment: You should add some stripping to deal with unwanted spaces. Or rather use `split()` instead of `split(' ')`

Comment: thanks, I'm new to python.
The only usage of split() that I knew was about assigning multiple values to different variables!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
rows = int(input('number of rows: '))
cols = int(input('number of columns: '))

matrix = []

for i in range(0, rows):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(0, cols):
        matrix[i].append(input(':: '))
        
print (matrix)
```

Comment: This doesn't match the input format the OP specified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).